# how i can read meta tag from template before load it on $routeChangeStart in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

i have angular app and server send to me dynamic html when routing to some page and this page have metatag for some use. i have to chenge url if the meta tag is not set before thmplate is load. how i can read meta tag befor load template in  $routeChangeStart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i can understand via your statement, is you want to get the meta information before loading the next page. Below is snippet, you will need to modify according to your requirement. If you are using Angular UI routing then this should work.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
      html = response.data; // Check the meta information and then
      //either move or stop propagation.    
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.